# Merging multiple rows of a column in a C# list based on other columns

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a generic C# list `List<Result>` Results which has several fields with several rows of data in it as follows of type `RESULT`

```
public class Result
{
    public int TrdID;
    public string Term;
    public double Price;
    public string Seller;
    public string Buyer;
    public bigint Quantity;
}
```

and the data is as follows

```
TrdID    Term      Price  Seller Buyer  Quantity
1000     201508      1     ABC    XYZ   10
1010     201508      2      ACB   PQR   10
1002     201507      1.5   ABX    PEW   20 
1002     201506      1.5   ABX    PEW   20
1002     201508      1.5   ABX    PEW   20
```

Now, I want to process the above data and return a single for a single unique `ID` provided for a particular `ID` all columns will be same except `Term`. For example I have three records for `ID 1002`, I want to merge them to a single record by converting Term to a DateTime and introducing two new columns saying `startDate` and `EndDate` and the expected results are as follows

Expected Result

```
   TrdID     StartDate     EndDate      Price  Seller Buyer  Quantity
    1000     08/01/2015    08/31/2015    1      ABC    XYZ   10
    1010     08/01/2015    08/31/2015    2      ACB    PQR   10
    1002     06/01/2015    08/31/2015    1.5    ABX    PEW   60
```

From the above data, one can see that I have two new columns named `StartDate` and `EndDate` instead of `Term` Column which is used to get the values for both `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
Also, there is a change to `Quantity` in the last row which is sum of all Quantities for a particular ID ie., `No.Of times ID repeated*Quantity`

Here, I have two cases to solve

**Case1:**
If there is only one record for particular `ID` say, `1000` then `StartDate` will be the first day of the month in Term column and EndDate will be the last day of the month in `Term` ie `08/01/2015 and 08/31/2015`.
No change to `Quantity`

**Case2:**
If there are multiple records for a particular `ID` say `1002`(all terms will be in a sequence) then `StartDate` will be first day of least month ie., `06/01/2015` and EndDate will be  last day of the highest month of Term column ie., 08/31/2015.
`Quantity=No.Of times ID repeated*Quantity` ie., `20*3=60`

My resultant list will of type

```
public class ProcessedResult
{
    public int TrdID;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public double Price;
    public string Seller;
    public string Buyer;
    public bigint Quantity;
}
```

**May I know a good way to solve this?**

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  `GroupBy`, `Min`, and `Max` seem like reasonable functions to use.

Comment: When there are multiple records with the same TrdID, will the values of Price,  Seller, Buyer and Quantity be the same for all of the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Provided that** the seller and the buyer would be the same as in the example you presented in your post, you need something like this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy( result => result.TrdID)
                 .Select( gr => {
                 var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.OrderBy(x => x.Term).First().Term, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                 var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Term).First().Term, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                      
                 return  new ProcessedResult
                 {
                     TrdID = gr.Key
                     StartDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1),
                     EndDate = (new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1)).AddMonth(1).AddDays(-1),
                     Price = gr.First().Price,
                     Seller = gr.First().Seller,
                     Buyer = gr.First().Buyer,
                     Quantity = gr.Sum(x=>x.Quantity)
                 } 
             });
```

Essentially, we make a group by of the results (list contains your results). The trick is done on how we construct the `StartDate` and `EndDate`. There we make an order by of the rows in the same group and we get the first one in order to get the `StartDate`'s string representation. Then we use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method, because we know the exact format of the DateTime. As far as the `EndDate` we make an `OrderByDescending`, in order we get the last date - we could make an OrderBy and get the last element, it's equivalent. Then we apply the DateTime.ParseExact again.

Comment: Correcton: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`This is because the `Term` is an string in my list

Comment: And I dont think this gives me StartDate as the first day of that month and EndDate as last day of the month that is in Term string field

Comment: I have made a minor change to your answer to remove the exception in the first comment by `DateTime.ParseExact(gr.OrderBy(x=>x.Term).First().Term` but this still doesn't give me the correct EndDate as `08/31/2015` instead it give `08/01/2015`

Comment: @Dev you are correct. My mistake :(. Please have a look know.

Comment: `startDate` and `endDate` again will just be of form `yyyyMM` and how come you use `SubString(4,6)` for just '201508`

Comment: I made some changes to your answer for a review and those changes game me correct results.

Comment: Sounds good :) ! What kind of changes? Could you please share it ? Thanks

Comment: I changed  `var startDate = gr.OrderBy(x=>x.Term).First();` to `DateTime.ParseExact(gr.OrderBy(x => x.Term).First().Term,                                 "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and instead of `SubString` I used `.Year and .Month` and done the samething for `endDate`

Comment: seems like my change wasn't approved. can you please make necessary changes so that I can accept that answer or I will have to write my own answer which I think isn't fair at all